# WebView font not correct in iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am using UIWebView for loading HTML files which are stored in the device. The fonts work well iOS 9.3, but when I run app in iOS 10.3, some default font is shown. Is it something which Apple has changed? or am I missing something?

I have used both, WKWebView and UIWebview, and they are behaving same in this regard.

On iOS 9.3:-

[image: This is on UIWebview on iOS 9.3]

On iOS 10.3:-

[image: This is on UIWebView on iOS 10.3]

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of digging I was able to figure out some keys which we declare in `info.plist` were hindering the UIWebView to load fonts. I am not sure is this a feature or bug.

Having `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` & `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia` set to `true` under AppTransportSecurity will stop UIWebView from loading any fonts which are being loaded from inside Javascript. (For my case it was AdobeEdge). So removing these keys will do the trick.